# Socket IO publish-subscribe model tricky

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, publish-subscribe

The problem is on socket.io client side.

I want first to create unconnected socket, and connect it to server after assigning all the listeners. The listeners cannot be set synchronously in one place in my application because there are some dependencies.

I know it's quite normal behavior normal for node.js! Just look at nodejs's sockets! I hope there's nothing wrong with my architecture. Socket io lacks [documentation](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client) and I can't find how to do what I want:

```
var socket = new io.Socket(); //creating empty socket.But this line does not work

//..... socket variable can be passed somewhere .....
//..... to another place in app .....

socket.on('message', callback);

//..... when everyone is ready and subscriben .....

socket.connect('some-url');
```

Comment: `var socket = new io.Socket(); //this does not work`

Answer (score 1):

So you want to start `socket.connect()` when something happens? So a classical `click` event listener like this:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    socket.connect('some-url')
});
```

If you want to listen to messages only after an event occurs, do the following:

```
socket.connect('some-url')
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
    socket.on('message', function() {
        // Your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: One small note: this "ready" happens on client side. The solution could be even more simple

Comment: Well, you have to communicate with other clients to know when you're ready. Unfortunately, the only way to do that is to speak with the server, which is connected to all the other clients. So only the server can tell you when you're ready, and can send you such an event.

Comment: Could you please give the code of creating the `socket` instance and everything would be great!

Comment: .... No, it's not great. socket can't receive "ready" unless it is not connected, and it should not be connected before the event. Let me edit your code to show the "ready" event comes from client side

Comment: The major problem is that I can't create a socket that **does not listen to any connections**. I can't create socket and assign listeners in different places of my code. And then connect socket. The socket is connected in constructor and that's THE ONLY CHOICE. That's differs dramatically from all other socket implementations in nodejs

Comment: I'm wondering if I'm missing something or I'm right? Socket-io-client has almost no documentation, so I've investigated its source code

Comment: Edited my answer :) Tell me if that's ok for you.

Comment: We've done a lot of job together. After all the investigation I say **that's impossible to create an unconnected socket in socket.io**

Comment: Yeah, but you don't need to listen/send events till you want to.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your issue correctly, if you create a socket without connecting immediately, all event listeners you added to it get disregarded once you connect it. That would be crap, I have not played with socket yet, so I cannot validate if it is true or not, but I have a solution for the problem

Create a facade which you add all your listeners too, once you are abale to connect to the server, connect, add your listeners (this should be done synchronously) and proxy all events dispatched by the socket through your facade.

Comment: The socket can't be created without connection. Try it yourself!

Answer (score 1):

I've found what I was looking for in the [socket.io documentatuion](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO)

They write we can disable connecting to the server in the moment of socket construction by setting this config:

> **auto connect** defaults to **true**
>
> When you call io.connect() should Socket.IO automatically establish a connection with the server.

So now we construct the object and it does not create connection immediately.

After constructing the unconnected socket you call method `create()`

I still don't know how to **turn off** the connection. So watch for updates